# Passing cables through a thermally insulated wall

Tags: cables, thermal, insulation

I am constructing a temperature control chamber. Of course, thermal insulation, is key in the development of the chamber. The idea is to insert different electronic circuits inside and study their response in temperature.

The problem which we are dealing with right now, is to decide how the cables will pass to the electronics inside the chamber to the outside. Naturally, the idea is to do this passage with the least possible insulation lost. I was thinking about a rubber grommet, or something that will adapt its shape to what´s passing through.

What is a good way to route cables through insulation?

Comment: Can you extend length of wires, and use small gauge wires? Extended-length wires should take a long path through insulation to outside.

Answer (score 3):

Having done aerospace environmental testing, I'll give you the method we used. The ovens had several ports in the side bigger than any likely cable. For a given piece of equipment the necessary cables were passed through the hole, than a piece of foam was used to plug the remaining apertures.

Don't worry overmuch about the heat/cold loss through a few inches of foam. If this does indeed make a critical difference, your heating/cooling system is underpowered.

Comment: I think the copper wire itself is the biggest problem.

Comment: @Janka - Yeah, but it's not a problem you can avoid, except perhaps by using a fiber-optic cable. At any rate, it's just something to live with.

Comment: Normal foam? You inserted it under pressure?